# How to align center + left/right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

My example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="col justify-content-center flex-column d-flex">
            left
        </div>
        <div class="col justify-content-center flex-column d-flex right">
            <a href="/">right</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.container div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

a {
    background-color: blue;   
}

.right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lawagabi/f7tp3x26/1/

How can I make text-align right in box with right without expanding it to the entire width?

Comment: explain in brief, what you want ? your question and description doesn't match

Comment: Can you explain more as question is not cLeAr

Comment: Not sure what you want https://jsfiddle.net/lawagabi/f7tp3x26/1/

Comment: I want to have blue box only under "right" text, not entire parent div.

Comment: Remove `col` from the class list. It uses `flex-grow: 1`, hence make the `a` fill its parent's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.container div` class is having an affect here. Wrap your anchor tag with a span with the `right` class to easily fix this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between my-auto">
        <div class="col justify-content-center flex-column d-flex">
            left
        </div>
        <div class="col justify-content-center flex-column d-flex">
          <span class="right"><a href="/">right</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qmnkgp7c/)